# Python sort list of dicts with lists inside

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have the following list structure:

```
[
    {'key1': 'value1', 
     'key2': [['mike', 'simmons', '54:17:47']], 
     'key3': 19390},
    {'key1': 'value1', 
     'key2': [['snart', 'simmons', '60:12:47']], 
     'key3': 19390}
]
```

I would like to sort this list by the second index of the key2 key ( I mean, by those 60:12:47 numbers)

I haven't found a standard way of doing this..

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way, assuming you want your values sorted *as strings*.

```
lst = [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [['snart', 'simmons', '60:12:47']], 'key3': 19390},
       {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [['mike', 'simmons', '54:17:47']], 'key3': 19390}]

res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['key2'][0][2])

# [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [['mike', 'simmons', '54:17:47']], 'key3': 19390},
#  {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [['snart', 'simmons', '60:12:47']], 'key3': 19390}]
```

Comment: you have to assign `sorted()` to something as it does not operate in place. You are probably running this in an interactive shell or something but OP might get confused. Alternatively, you can do `lst.sort(..)`. And the *numbers* are sorted as if they were strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted` with a comparator that uses that value:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda d: d['key2'][0][2])
```